# What is the closed form of the following expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, closed-form

I need some help figuring out the closed form of the following expansion.

```
T[n]=T[n-1]+T[1]*T[n-2]+T[2]*T[n-3]+T[3]*T[n-4]+...+T[n-1]
```

I haven't done this type of math in a while. I am solving a programming problem and this turns out to be the answer to the program. I am just curious to find out if it has a closed form in mathematics. It the tags I specify are inaccurate, please feel free to add others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This equation of reccurence is well known. It defines the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). There is a closed form for the $n$-th term of the sequence in term of a binomial coefficient:
$$
T[n] = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}
$$

Comment: Wow. Thanks. By the looks of it I thought there should be a closed-form but deriving it was a bit over my head. And thanks for the link too. +1